# How do you search for PL/SQL code in Oracle forms fmb files?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

How do you find code if you don't know which Form it's in.  If you know the form you can search pl sql but what if you don't know form?

For example I know the name of a field that is used in some code I want to see but don't know where code is at.

Comment: Search text in files. I use total commander for that. Works flawless.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend FormsTool - it understands the FMB, RDF and PLL formats natively, you can optionally search in object attributes as well as code. It shows the code search results with context (i.e. a few lines before and after).

http://www.orcl-toolbox.com/formstool/

Comment: We have founded FormsTool to be very helpful not only searching in forms but also comparing different versions of the same form.

Comment: +1, never heard of it. It's a bit pricey. Does it work with Forms 6i?

Comment: I used it on Forms 6i FMBs and RDFs just recently (unbelievably we still have a Forms 6i app running!). It's easily worth the money if your employer expects you to do impact analysis on a not-small application, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I always use total commander for this, it is easy.
You can find text in fmb's.

You can also open all your fmb's in one forms builder and then search over all of them.
This is ofcourse no option if you got 1000 fmb's or so.

Third possibility is to convert your fmb's to xml and search in the xml files.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/migrate.32/e13368/appmgr_forms.htm#CHDCFFIC

Answer (score 1):

I just use [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).  There are [versions for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm), too.

Comment: You can use FINDSTR for windows. For example:
FINDSTR /i /m /c:"sms_gsm_code" This finds all files, which have string "sms_gsm_code".

Comment: True enough, I just like grep.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FormsTool (that are not free) you can use whatever tool that allows you to do text searches inside files. Myself I'm using PSPad freeware editor and its 'Search / Replace in Files...) function.